# Redirect website from beta to live folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a http://www.nz-lifestyle.com/beta/ website which runs on http://www.nz-lifestyle.com/ live site also but I want to redirect the beta site live site when any user visit to beta site.

Can you please provide the htaccess rule for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /beta/ /
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^standard-business-cards/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=permanent,L]
```